# For which values of $a$ does this function has an inverse?

Tags: calculus, functions, trigonometry, inverse

I have the following function: $$f(x)=\begin{cases}
\frac{1-x}{x} & x\geq1\\
a-\arctan x & x<1
\end{cases}$$
and it is clear that the upper half is always invertible, so the only part we care about is the bottom part. It's inverse is $\tan(a-x),$ so it appears as if it always has an inverse, so why ask for which $a$ values? Did I make a mistake? How do you solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, $f$ has NOT always an inverse.
You are not comparing the values of the function $f$ on both sides $(-\infty,1)$ and $[1,+\infty)$.

For instance, fora $a=0$, $f(1)=f(0)=0$ which means that $f$ is non injective in $\mathbb{R}$ and therefore it is not invertible. So invertibility DEPENDS on $a$!

Note that $f$ restricted to $[1,+\infty)$ and  $f$ restricted to $(-\infty,1)$ are strictly decreasing.

We have that
$$f([1,+\infty))=\left\{\frac{1}{x}-1\;:\; x\geq 1\right\}=(-1,0]$$
and
$$f((-\infty,1))=\{a-\arctan(x)\;:\; x<1\}=\left(a-\frac{\pi}{4},a+\frac{\pi}{2}\right).$$
In order to have invertibility such sets should be disjoint.
Why? Recall the definition of a bijective function and its inverse.

Can you take it from here?

Comment: So how can I find the values of $a$ where it is indeed inverse? I can't compare for each $x\in\mathbb{R}$

Comment: How do I find their sets? I have here both $a$ and $x$ to take into account

Comment: Start with $([1,+∞))$. It does not depend on $a$.

Comment: Yes, I got the first part, the second one is harder.

Comment: So the solution is for each: $\frac{\pi}{4}\leq a$  or $a\leq -1-\frac{\pi}{2}$

Comment: Thank you!! so $a= \pi / 4$ is a solution as well?

Comment: Yes , you are right. $a=\pi/4$ is a solution. Your solution is correct.

Answer (score 0):

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}
\frac{1-x}{x}& x\geq1 & f(1^+)=f(1)=0 \\
a-\arctan x & x<1 & f(1^-)=a-\frac{\pi}{4}
\end{cases}$$
so you need to $$a-\frac{\pi}{4}\geq f(1)$$it means $$a\geq\frac{\pi}{4}+0$$ it is becasus
$$f_1(x)=\frac{1-x}{x} \text{  decreasing  }    f'_1=-\frac1{x^2} <0    \space,\forall x>1\\
f_2(x)=a-arctanx \space\text{   decreasing   }f'_2=0-\frac1{1+x^2}<0 , \forall x<1$$
so the function can have inverse function at all

Comment: why does the fact that they are both decreasing mean that all I need to do is to do some comparison the $f(1-)$ and $f(1+)$

Comment: I made it complete. bot of the function have $f'<0$

Comment: I understood that they are decreasing, I just didn't understand why does that help?

Comment: @ArielYael: please take a look at this https://www.desmos.com/calculator/q2bcaanish and scroll $a$ to understand  very well.

Comment: Ok I think I got it! Since they are both decreasing all I need to do is compare the lowest point of the left function with the heighest point in the right function, which are both $1^\pm$. But how do I explain this in a formal way?

Comment: robert z: did it very well by detail,see above

Comment: it appears then as if $\frac{\pi}{4}$ is also a solution